Can't resolve './zstd.win32-x64-msvc.node' in ...node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd
I have a react node js typescript project I'm working on via my m2 chip mac where I'm trying to get MongoDB and mongoose setup on.
I've installed the basic mongodb package via npm and am getting the above error as well as the following:
\WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 31:28-65
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.win32-x64-msvc.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 33:28-70
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-win32-x64-msvc' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 49:28-61
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.darwin-x64.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 51:28-66
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-x64' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 61:28-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.darwin-arm64.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 80:30-67
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-x64-musl.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 82:30-72
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-x64-musl' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 91:30-66
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-x64-gnu.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 93:30-71
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-x64-gnu' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 105:30-69
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm64-musl.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 107:30-74
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm64-musl' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 116:30-68
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm64-gnu.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 118:30-73
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm64-gnu' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 129:28-70
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 131:28-75
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm-gnueabihf' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 22:11-28
@ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 18:12-36
@ ./node_modules/express/index.js 11:0-41
@ ./server/index.ts 8:34-52

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 23:19-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kerberos' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 45:35-75
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aws-sdk/credential-providers' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 57:35-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'gcp-metadata' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 69:22-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'snappy' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 81:22-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'socks' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 94:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws4' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 108:34-70
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in '/Users/nikoicardo/Desktop/node.js projects/propertyManage/propertyManage/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45

23 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-arm64/zstd.darwin-arm64.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
@ ./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js 63:28-68
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 34:20-47
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 61:26-79
@ ./server/db/connectDb.ts 13:18-36
@ ./server/index.ts 11:20-45\

Whats weird is its seemingly looking for other OS related packaged in my installation. Am I doing something wrong with installing mongodb? For reference, here is my package.json and webpack.server.config.js`

package.json:
{
  "name": "propertymanage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a property management portal for tenants and owners",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist-server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run front\" \"npm run back\"",
    "front": "webpack serve --config webpack.client.config.mjs",
    "back": "nodemon --watch 'server/**/*.ts' --exec 'webpack --config webpack.server.config.mjs && node dist-server/server.js' --ext ts",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "webpack --config webpack.client.config.mjs --mode production",
    "build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.mjs --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.24.1",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "webpack": "^5.92.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.39",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4"
  }
}


webpack.server.config.js:
 import path from "path";
      import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
      const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url); // get the resolved path to the file
      const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename); // get the name of the directory

      export default {
            entry: "./server/index.ts", // Entry point of your server-side TypeScript code
            target: "node", // Compile for Node.js environment
            output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist-server"), // Output directory for server build
                filename: "server.js", // Output file name
            },
            devtool: "source-map", // Enable source maps for easier debugging
            resolve: {
                extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".node"], // Resolve TypeScript and JavaScript files
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /.ts$/,
                        use: "ts-loader",
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                    },
                ],
            },
            node: {
                        __dirname: false, // For proper directory handling in Node.js
                        __filename: false,
            },
      };

I have tried a number of things from completely uninstalling the package, removing all packages, clearing the npm cache. Whats weird is the package seems to be up to date with the latest version of node.js as well as the m2 mac. Im wondering if I need to install a sub package for mac m2?
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is a big hang up on my project.
